# CORS enabled on AWS API, but still getting "No Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-web-services, cors

I recently restructured my API on AWS Gateway to make all my Lambda functions use proxy integration - before that, every single parameter was passed in as a path parameter (awful, I know.)

I never had any issues with CORS then, and I've tried several things over the past few hours to fix the issue discussed in the topic line.

First, I used a proxy resource and used an "ANY" method, but when that gave me CORS issues, I enabled CORS on the API method and tried again - still nothing. So, I tried changing it so that it was a "POST" request instead and enabling CORS - still nothing. And I made sure to deploy after every setting change. Then, I got rid of the proxy and instead just made a "POST" method with CORS enabled, and still nothing.

I'm using Angular's http post method.

Edit:

I'm using Angular 1.6.4, and this is the code I'm using to call the API:

```
    this.checkRegistered = function(email){
        var data = { Email : email};
        var toSend = JSON.stringify(data);
        return $http.post('link', toSend);
    };
```

That's in my service for the angular module, and it's being called from this function in the controller:

```
    function CheckIsRegistered(email)
    {
        return userService.checkRegistered(email).then(function(res){
        if (res.data.statusCode === 200){
            return res.data.body;
        }});
    }
```

I've configured all the parameters so that "Email" is what it should be expecting, and I did replace the word 'link' with the actual link.

When I enable CORS through the console, I assign the headers as follows:

Access-Control-Allow-Headers: 'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*'

This is especially infuriating because I've actually worked with this exact issue before and solved it fairly easily, but now that I'm using Lambda's proxy integration I've run into this issue again and I can't quite seem to figure it out.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at the headers being returned? at the request being made? Is it a preflight? not a preflight?

Comment: (1) Which version of angular? (2) What are the request and response headers? (3) Can you show some relevant code?

Comment: Not that this solves your problem, but if you're communicating with AWS via client side, does that mean your keys are exposed? Bad idea.

Comment: Make sure you deploy the API after you enable CORS headers. It's easy to forget to do the deploy step, and the changes don't go into affect until you do.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem - I had to add the headers for CORS to the Lambda response. Here's the code snippet for anyone else having similar problems:

```
                    connection.query('arbitrary query', [params], function (error, results, field) {
            if (!error)
            {
                connection.end();
                var responseBody = results; 
                response = { statusCode: 200, 
                headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"}, 
                body: JSON.stringify(responseBody)}; 
                callback(null, response);
            }
```

I put the querying line in there just for context of what "response" is.